# How can i add redux middleware dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

rtk-query is my daily use lib thanks for the great work. I inject reducer with redux-injectors but can`t use caching and other features of rtk-query. Does it have any lib injecting middleware dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux middleware are normally only added once, as the store is created.  This is because the `applyMiddleware()` enhancer has to be defined as part of the store creation process.

I *have* seen a few attempts to create a middleware that would let you dynamically modify the original middleware setup. I haven't tried any of them, but you may be able to look at these and either use them as-is or as a source of inspiration:

- https://github.com/pofigizm/redux-dynamic-middlewares
- https://github.com/andyjessop/redux-dynamic-registry
- https://github.com/yldio/redux-replaceable-middleware

Answer (score 1):

As additional information for future readers: You should probably not inject additional APIs later on (most applications should really only have one api!), but use one shared api that is loaded from the beginning ad inject additional endpoints into that api following the [documented approach of code splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) using `api.injectEndpoints`.